# Bugs in awarding of badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have noted some bugs in the awarding of badges:

1. I did my first retag on my [question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/how-were-negative-numbers-first-used-in-physics) and was thus entitled to receive an Organizer badge but never got it.
2. I saw a [user](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/600/tidymonkey81) who did not have enough reputation to flag posts but still earned the Citizen Patrol badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of these are not bugs.

For the first, if you check the more thorough badge requirements at [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397), you will see that to get Organizer you must retag someone else's question, not your own. In general I recommend checking that post if you have questions about badges, as many badges have additional criteria not listed in their description.

For the second, under certain circumstances a new user is able to flag posts with less than the required [15 reputation](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). In this instance the user in question did indeed submit a flag. You can even see from [their profile](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/600/tidymonkey81?tab=topactivity) that they have 1 helpful flag. (The flag wasn't yet handled when this question was posted but has since been dealt with.) I won't disclose  exactly what the flag was for, but the badge was awarded properly.

Comment: The circumstances under which a user can flag posts with less than the required 15 reputation are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349241/771581).